# while saving model: list index (0) out of range

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

this is my face_landmark.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

def get_landmark_model(saved_model="models/pose_model"):
  model = keras.models.load_model(saved_model)
  return model
```

and in camera.py, I am importing it and using its function

```
from face_detector import get_face_detector, find_faces
from face_landmarks import get_landmark_model, detect_marks
face_model = get_face_detector()
landmark_model = get_landmark_model()
```

in face_landmarks.py **error is raising when I am trying to load the model**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

While loading the model, provide file extension as well.
For example

```
def get_landmark_model(saved_model="models/pose_model.h5"):
  model = keras.models.load_model(saved_model)
  return model
```

here **h5** is the extension of model.

Comment: I don't have any `pose_model.h5`, I've `models/pose_model` only.
Can you tell from where I can download that `pose_model.h5` file
And reference of this code is https://gist.github.com/vardanagarwal/186127695cd8f33ba19f392454d539b1

Comment: You are probably using the `SaveModel` format: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#savedmodel_format

Comment: @AloneTogether yes

Comment: are you training your own model or downloading from somewhere? if training your own, use `model.save('modelname.h5')` while saving the model. And when needed to load, use `keras.models.load_model('modelname.h5')`.

Comment: @MuhammadDaniyal yes I have downloaded it from github
`tf.saved_model.load(saved_model)` I tried this and it worked.
Anyways thank you MuhammadDaniyal..I'll use `model.save('modelname.h5')` next time to create my model..this was new for me..:)